To sort a sequence of numbers of a dataframe in specific order
My Input

lst = [ '6', '7', '8', '9', '9.1', '10.1', '10.2', '13.1', '13.2',
'14.1',  '14.2', '15.1', '15.2', '16.1', '16.2', '17', '11.1.1',
'11.1.2', '11.2.1', '11.2.2', '12.1.1', '12.1.2', '12.2.1', '12.2.2' ]

Expected Output

output = [  '6', '7', '8', '9', '9.1', '10.1', '11.1.1', '12.1.1',
'11.1.2', '12.1.2', '13.1', '14.1', '15.1', '16.1', '10.2', 11.2.1',
'12.2.1', '11.2.2', '12.2.2', '13.2', '14.2', '15.2', '16.2', '17' ]

My current code
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)

df ['one'] = df[0].astype(str).str.split(".", n=1).str[0]

df ['two'] = df[0].astype(str).str.split(".", n=2).str[1]

df ['three'] = df[0].astype(str).str.split(".", n=2).str[2]

df ['three'] = df['three'].fillna('0')



df ['one'] = pd.to_numeric(df['one'], errors='coerce')

df ['two'] = pd.to_numeric(df['two'], errors='coerce')

df ['three'] = pd.to_numeric(df['three'], errors='coerce')



sorted_df = df.sort_values(by = ['two', 'one', 'three' ], na_position = 'first' )



sorted_df ['greater'] = sorted_df['one'].gt(sorted_df['one'].tail(1).max())

sorted_df = sorted_df.sort_values('greater', kind = 'megasort' )

print(sorted_df)

Not able to get an expected O/P
Tried above code but could not reach desired o/p

Why is '17' sorted after the rest? can you explain the expected logic? What if you had an extra '18'? And extra '18'/'18.1.1'/'18.1.2'/'19'?

Also you code seems to give the expected output, can clarify what is the issue?

Use Version from packaging.version library:
from packaging.version import Version

lst = [ '6', '7', '8', '9', '9.1', '10.1', '10.2', '13.1', '13.2', '14.1', '14.2', '15.1', '15.2', '16.1', '16.2', '17', '11.1.1', '11.1.2', '11.2.1', '11.2.2', '12.1.1', '12.1.2', '12.2.1', '12.2.2' ]
output = sorted(lst, key=Version)
print(output)
# ['6', '7', '8', '9', '9.1', '10.1', '10.2', '11.1.1', '11.1.2', '11.2.1', '11.2.2', '12.1.1', '12.1.2', '12.2.1', '12.2.2', '13.1', '13.2', '14.1', '14.2', '15.1', '15.2', '16.1', '16.2', '17']

Note that this approach is actually preferable to splitting and sorting as you showed in the question. This is because the library has already implemented lots of special cases and enables to correctly compare some very rarely used version numbers.
References:

Version Handling - Packaging


This doesn't match the expected output, 10.2 should come after 16.1

@mozway You are right. But here, I assume that the OP is trying to sort version numbers. Let's see what the OP responds to your comments and my answer. The question seems to have some inconsistencies, I assume these are just OP's mistakes, which do not reflect the actual intent.

I have to admit that I initially thought a version-like/natural sort was expected, but in their attempt they explicitly sort by ['two', 'one', 'three' ], which seems to go with the expected output. Let's wait and see ;)

These version components have well-known names: major.minor.patch.
According to your ['two', 'one', 'three'] rule, the output should be 6, 7, 8, 9, 17, 9.1, 10.1, ...
If that is the case, you can try this:
output = (
    pd.Series(lst)
    .str.split(".", expand=True)
    .fillna("-1")
    .astype(int)
    .sort_values([1, 0, 2])
    .apply(lambda row: ".".join([str(i) for i in row if i != -1]), axis=1)
    .to_list()
)

